# PowerShell Indexing

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare two files based off of variables capture from the first input file. If I have `$inputvariable` and I want to quickly check it against the contents of the second input file, how do I perform that? I've tried using `Get-Content`, however the second file has roughly 500,000 entries. The first file has around 1000, so even with breaking, it still checks every line from the first input file rather slowly. Essentially, is there a way to index the second input file as if it were entered into a database and quickly search?

Comment: if the lines in the 1st file are unique, you can use a hashtable as a lookup table. then the lookup of 2nd file items would be very, very fast.

Comment: Each of the lines in the first file are unique, I just am parsing out certain variables. The second file is pretty static. How would I perform a hash table if the variable I'm capturing on is $inputvariable and Im trying to compare it to the second file to find a match, output it to a third file, then break (and drop to the next line in the first file).

Comment: the benefit of a lookup table is very, very fast lookups. [*grin*] so put what you want to use as your "this is unique" thing in the key and the full line in the value. then iterate thru the 2nd file checking for "is the unique stuff here in the lookup table?" with something like `$LookupTable[$UniqueThing]` it that returns anything, then the item is already in the 1st file.